# Identify points contained inside a linestring

Tags: postgis

This question is, I think, very simple but I can't resolve it by myself.

I have a table '`cable`' like this :

```
CREATE TABLE cable (
  id uuid primary_key,
  the_geom geometry(LineString, 2154)
);
```

And another table let's call it `partpoint`

```
CREATE TABLE partpoint (
  id uuid primary key,
  the_geom geometry(Point, 2154)
);
```

I want to know if, for a specific `partpoint`, this `partpoint` is part of linestring in the `cable` table. The first request was :

```
SELECT id 
FROM cable 
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(the_geom, 
                  (SELECT the_geom 
                   FROM partpoint 
                   WHERE id=<anUuid>))
```

But this does not work :-( Do I need to loop over all the table ? (with a for loop).

Comment: Show a little of each of your data points? Edit your question to add the results of `SELECT id, AsEWKT(the_geom) FROM cable LIMIT 5` and `SELECT id, AsEWKT(the_geom) FROM partpoint LIMIT 5`. At a guess, you need to handle real number tolerances, but its hard to say without seeing the data.

Comment: You should remove your [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/247014/edit) and instead post it as an **answer** :)

Answer (score 1):

Find it ! I didn't know at that time that you can join spatially on a table. So the resulting query is :

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM partpoint pp 
 JOIN cable c ON (ST_contains(the_geom, pp.the_geom) 
 WHERE ST_CONTAINS(c.the_geom, 
                  (SELECT the_geom 
                   FROM partpoint 
                   WHERE id=<anUuid>))
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause is not necessary. You can just add this: `WHERE pp.id=<anUuid>` **OR** `JOIN (SELECT the_geom 
                   FROM partpoint 
                   WHERE id=<anUuid>) ON [...]`